# Rotating GUI.Box Causes Clipping

Tags: user-interface, rotation, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to rotate 2 different GUI Boxes's on the Z Axis. Each box will have a different Z axis value. The following image shows how I am trying to make them appear(I made the following image in photoshop):

[image]

**My Problem:** I am unable to rotate my boxes on the Z axis without clipping occurring. I can successfully rotate my panels on the x and y axis but not the Z without clipping occurring. Also can I have 2 boxes with a different z rotation using GUI.Matrix (I've read in other questions that this isn't possible)?

This is what happens:
[image]

Any ideas how I can achieve the rotation that is shown in my first image?

```
void OnGUI() {
    Matrix4x4 guiMatrixOrig = GUI.matrix;
    GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, Quaternion.Euler(0, 45, 0), new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)); 
    GUI.Box (new Rect (10,10,400, 400), "Loader Menu");
    GUI.matrix = guiMatrixOrig;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked a while ago but.. if anyone else trys to do something alike he should try to use the [GUIUtility.RotateAroundPivot function.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUIUtility.RotateAroundPivot.html), moving multiple Boxes without clipping should work that way.